# How to find count of multiple columns

Tags: mysql

How to find count of multiple columns in a table

```
create table foo (key1 int(11),  key2 int(11) ..)
```

I would like to do select count(*) for key1 and count(*) for key2 from foo in a single query, is it possible?

Comment: It will be the same for both, since every row has both columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count the distinct values you can do:

```
select count(distinct key1), count(distinct key2)
from foo;
```

If you want counts by values, you can use `union all`:

```
select key1, count(*)
from foo
group by key1
union all
select key2, count(*)
from foo
group by key2;
```